# HTTP requests Node JS: Response construction in chunks

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Hi everyone I was looking up on how to make HTTP requests in Node JS, when I found the following template

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

I had a couple of questions regarding this, if someone could answer them with an example (or something like a situation) where these things come into action it would be really helpful.

1. As far as my understandings of callbacks go this call back would be invoked when the response of the endpoint has been returned, so I really don't understand the requirement of the `response.on('data', callback_for_appending_chunk)`. Is that really required? Can't we just assign `str` to the data of the response.
2. If something wrong happens with the request, is there some built in time out to take care of aborting the process, if yes where can I find details related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe its well explained in their documentation, you can find more details on the chunks of data and their built-in timeout to handle such scenarios from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback).

Comment: I went through the documentation, but for the chunk part I don't see any reason why assigning the value directly to `str` would be a problem, appreciate if you clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'data' callback handles it only when it receives a response, and the end event does not fire until it has consumed a response. Its well explained in this [section](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest).

> This object is created internally and returned from http.request(). It represents an in-progress request whose header has already been queued. The header is still mutable using the setHeader(name, value), getHeader(name), removeHeader(name) API. The actual header will be sent along with the first data chunk or when calling request.end().
>
> During the 'response' event, one can add listeners to the response
> object; particularly to listen for the 'data' event.
>
> If no 'response' handler is added, then the response will be entirely
> discarded. However, if a 'response' event handler is added, then the
> data from the response object must be consumed, either by calling
> response.read() whenever there is a 'readable' event, or by adding a
> 'data' handler, or by calling the .resume() method. Until the data is
> consumed, the 'end' event will not fire. Also, until the data is read
> it will consume memory that can eventually lead to a 'process out of
> memory' error.

To answer your second question,
Yes, there is a default timeout of 5000 milliseconds, more information can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout).

Comment: I'm still not completely clear, so here's my understanding, I'll also highlight where I'm not clear.
So when a request is sent it is processed on the server end and then the response is returned post which the call back is invoked (this means that I already have the complete response for the request when I enter the callback).
So my doubt is what is the meaning of **chunk-wise appending to `str`** can't I directly assign it to `str`?

Comment: Yes you are right, the entire response can be appended to the str, however, in case of retrieving large volumes of data, retrieving it causes a huge performance lag, thus data is [retrieved in chunks](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-offset-fetch-feature-loading-large-volumes-of-data-using-limited-resources-with-ssis/) using separate callbacks for better architecture and performance improvement,